# Where can I download the OpenVPN client?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, openvpn

I would like to download this version of the OpenVPN client for my Windows 8.1 (x64) computer:

[image: client]

However, I can't find the official link.

On [OpenVPN download page](https://openvpn.net/index.php/download/community-downloads.html), only the OpenVPN GUI is provided.

If I google to find a download link, I only found external downloads (like Software informer, CNet donwload, ...), which I don't trust.

Where is the official download page for this client?

Comment: Looks like a GUI of the commercial version...?

Comment: @Ramhound: nothing wrong... I just feel this client is more modern than the OpenVPN Gui

Comment: You don't really need that client anymore. Follow the instructions: http://www.vpntutorials.com/tutorials/openvpn-client-setup-tutorial-for-windows-8/ to set up your OpenVPN GUI.

Comment: @George: I don't get you. What's the point of you tuto?

Comment: @SteveB the `OpenVPN Client` is not supported any more, you will have to go with the `GUI` executable if you don't already have the client installed in your computer and the tutorial I referred to is one of the best on how to set it up and have it up and working withing minutes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### I can't find the official link.

The particular client (openvpn-client.msi) you wish to install does not seem to be available any more on the OpenVPN website.

- It was located at http://swupdate.openvpn.net/downloads.
- This redirects to http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html.
- openvpn-client.msi is not there.

It is available at [OpenVPN Desktop Client Setup -Windows](http://help.unotelly.com/support/articles/184301-openvpn-desktop-client-setup-windows-) (Hosted by UnoTelly).

> UnoTelly is currently offering OpenVPN on our UK, US, and Canada
>   servers for customers who are not able to connect to the PPTP VPN due
>   to port blocks and filtering.

Source [OpenVPN Info and Files - Please Read](http://help.unotelly.com/support/solutions/articles/184300-openvpn-info-and-files-please-read-)

---

> **Windows Notes**
>
> OpenVPN for Windows can be installed from the self-installing exe file
>   on the OpenVPN download page. Remember that OpenVPN will only run on
>   Windows XP or later. Also note that OpenVPN must be installed and run
>   by a user who has administrative privileges (this restriction is
>   imposed by Windows, not OpenVPN). The restriction can be sidestepped
>   by running OpenVPN in the background as a service, in which case even
>   non-admin users will be able to access the VPN, once it is installed.
>   More discussion on OpenVPN + Windows privilege issues.
>
> **Official OpenVPN Windows installers include [OpenVPN-GUI](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN-GUI), which
>   allows managing OpenVPN connections from a system tray applet. Other
>   [GUI](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/graphical-user-interface.html) applications are also available.**

Source [HOWTO Install](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#install).

---

> **The official OpenVPN release for Windows ships with a GUI frontend
>   called simply "OpenVPN-GUI"** and can be found in the .\bin\
>   subdirectory of the installation path, with shortcuts placed on the
>   desktop and start menu unless unselected during program installation.

Reference [Downloads](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).

[image]

Source [OpenVPN GUI (for
Windows)](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN-GUI):

Answer (score 2):

"...I would like to download this version of the OpenVPN client for my Windows 8.1 (x64) computer..."

Here it is

http://swupdate.openvpn.org/downloads/shield/openvpn-connect.msi